# How to check updated ffmpeg static version / consistent version names

Tags: ffmpeg

i am checking the ffmpeg installed in my

- aws ec2 (centos):
  ffmpeg version **N-60236-gffb000fff8-static**
- With my local machine. (mac) it shows:
  ffmpeg version **5.0**

Looking at the johnvansickle FAQ, the screenshots show similar ffmpeg version formats (with the N-xxxxxx) How do i know that the static reference is also version 5.0?

The reason I ask is that i'm getting an error in aws but i couldn't reproduce it in my mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N-xxxxx builds are nightly builds (thus starts with "N"). I don't know how to decode the filename (I thought "gffb000fff8" might be git hash but it does't seem like so) but along with `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` there is `readme.txt` file which contains the build and version info. The build info string includes the date it was built and the version is the git hash string. You can compare them to the date of v5.0 or relative position of the git hash on git history.

I don't know what the nature of the errors are, but I know that the log formats have changed some since v5.0 (I don't use nightly so I cannot comment on when those changes were first applied on the trunk).

[Edit]

With Gyan's help, I found the git commit date of your nightly: 22/01/03. And v5.0 release was on 22/02/01

So, the nightly is an older release, and as I mentioned above, it's log format could be different between these 2 versions.

Comment: The initial `g` stands for git. The rest is the commit hash.

Comment: May be worth pointing out that johnvansickle's serves nightly builds as latest, but that the latest stable is not necessarily available. e.g. 5.0.1 and 4.4.2 have been out since April, but the [old releases page](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/old-releases/) currently only offers 4.4.1 as latest stable.